# Git command to see when a specific feature branch was merged into the integration branch

Tags: git

I know I can use the git log --graph feature to do this but this provides too much information.

Is there a git command that tells you when and by who a specific branch name was merged into an integration branch?

Or maybe a way to modify the git log --graph to only display these two branches--the integration branch and the feature branch I specify.

Answer (score 0):

> Or maybe a way to modify the git log --graph to only display these two branches--the integration branch and the feature branch I specify.

It sounds like the `--branches[=<pattern>]` option will get you what you want. From the help page:

> ```
> Pretend as if all the refs in refs/heads are listed on the command line as
> <commit>. If <pattern> is given, limit branches to ones matching given shell
> glob. If pattern lacks ?, *, or [, /* at the end is implied.
> ```